# Running Cocoa Pods application on machine where it isnt installed

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I recently created an iOS project utilizing cocoa pods to install AfNetworking. I zipped the project and send to someone to check out.  They are saying they cannot run the project and they are getting an error because the libpods.a is missing.  My assumption is that they didnt open the project from the xcworkspace and tried to open via xcproj, but havent been able to confirm.

Someone who receives a cocoapods based application doesn't need to run pod:install on their machine do they?? (They do not have cocoapods on their machine. )

Comment: If your project is using cocoa pod then your friend needs to install it on their machine too in order to use the project.

Comment: Your friend has to run the "pod install" in his system.

Comment: These two comments are incorrect. Your friend can view / run / build the project as-is (as long as they open it using the xcworkspace NOT .xcodeproj). If they want to update the pods then they would need to install Cocoapods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the project folder (including the workspace and all subfolders such as the `Pods` folder) has been zipped in its entirety, and you've got it working on your machine, then the pods folder and its contents should be present, and the problem is probably that the project has been opened instead of the workspace.

You don't need Cocoapods installed at build time. You need it to create and populate the pods project and set up the workspace, but once that done, nothing else is needed until you want to update the Podfile.

Comment: This is correct - as long as you also zipped up the `Pods/` directory that Cocoapods generates for your project, they'll be able to build it without installing Cocoapods. They'll just need to open the `xcworkspace`.